# How do I get data or percentage displayed in libreoffice pie chart?

Tags: charts, libreoffice-calc

I need to get a pie-chart with values - can libreoffice do it?

[image: pie chart sample]

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes

Right-click on the chart and choose edit.
 Right-click on the pie and choose insert data labels.
 Right-click on a data label and choose format data labels.
 You can choose Placement, set to Inside.
 You can check the box to show value as percentage.

Comment: The title of the question can be misleading when considering this answer. This won't calculate percentages based on values but will actually take your values and put a "%" sign behind. In addition to the steps above make sure to untick "Show value as number" if you want to have percentages on your chart that actually represent the size of the slices.